# TSQL XML Parsing

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

I have an XML block that I am sending to my stored procedure.

```
<vehicles>
<licensePlate>ABC123</licensePlate>
<vehicle>
  <model>Ford</model>
  <color>Blue</color>
  <carPool>
     <employee>
        <empID>111</empID>
     </employee>
     <employee>
        <empID>222</empID>
     </employee>
     <employee>
        <empID>333</empID>
     </employee>
  </carPool>
</vehicle>
</vehicles>
```

I then use a select statement to parse out the data that I need from this XML block.

```
INSERT INTO licensePlates (carColor, carModel, licensePlate, empID, dateAdded) 
    SELECT  ParamValues.x2.value('color[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)'),
            ParamValues.x2.value('model[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)'),
            ParamValues.x2.value('../licensePlate[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)'),
            @empID,
            GETDATE()
    FROM   @xmlData.nodes('/vehicles/vehicle') AS ParamValues(x2)
```

I need to store the XML contained within the tag `<carPool>` into a column in this table.

So I'm getting this XML block, and need a piece of that to not be parsed and just go directly to the table:

```
<carPool>
     <employee>
        <empID>111</empID>
     </employee>
     <employee>
        <empID>222</empID>
     </employee>
     <employee>
        <empID>333</empID>
     </employee>
  </carPool>
```

How can I go about doing this?

This is an example of what the inserted record would look like.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[You can insert the node directly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/185681)

```
INSERT INTO licensePlates (carColor, carModel, licencePlate, empId, dateAdded, carPoolMembers) 
    SELECT  ParamValues.x2.value('color[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)'),
            ParamValues.x2.value('model[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)'),
            ParamValues.x2.value('../licensePlate[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)'),
            @empID,
            GETDATE(),
            ParamValues.x2.query('./carPool')
    FROM   @xmlData.nodes('/vehicles/vehicle') AS ParamValues(x2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your stored procedure has a parameter called `@Input XML`, you could use this code:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable(XmlColumn)
   SELECT @input.query('/vehicles/vehicle/carPool')
```

That should select the `<carPool>` XML tag and insert it into the XML column of your table.

Comment: The issue is, I'm sending multiple blocks at the same time so there could be 3 root vehicle tags and its inserting 3 separate records into the table. Now with your example, its adding it to the correct column but its adding all 3 blocks of `/vehicles/vehicle/carPool` to every carPoolMembers column. So it's very close but the column for this carpool data contains all of the carPool records for all 3 blocks, not just its own block

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
SELECT  ParamValues.x2.value('color[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)'),
        ParamValues.x2.value('model[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)'),
        ParamValues.x2.value('../licensePlate[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)'),
        @empID,
        GETDATE()
        , carPoolMembers = x2.query('./carPool')
FROM   @xmlData.nodes('/vehicles/vehicle') AS ParamValues(x2)
```